# Is there a difference between Keras Dense layer and Pytorch's nn.linear layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I noticed the definition of [Keras Dense layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/) says: Activation function to use. If you don't specify anything, no activation is applied (ie. "linear" activation: a(x) = x).

So if we have a code like:

```
model.add(Dense(10, activation = None))
```

Is it basically the same as:

```
nn.linear(128, 10)
```

?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is the same. `model.add (Dense(10, activation = None))` or `nn.linear(128, 10)` is the same, because it is not activated in both, therefore if you don't specify anything, no activation is applied. It is so!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes if there is no activation it's just a linear layer.